# 2D charge density contour plot (how to get arbitrary 'Z' values in the plot using python)

Tags: quantum-espresso, python, charge-density

I need to generate a contour plot from a file (named abc.gnu) which has X, Y and Z columns of data. It has 1000000 rows of data. I have got the contour plot with a python code (shown at the end). What I need is to know the 'Z' values in any arbitrary place of choice (or to see 'Z' values in different regions of the contour plot). If I zoom any particular region, still the color bar is showing the same min and max values, so I can't get any information of 'Z' values in the zoomed region as well. Do you have any idea to solve this for my used file. I have given my used python script at the end. Any other idea to get more effective 2D contour plot is also welcome.

[image]

**Used Python Code for the contour plot**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data=pd.read_csv('abc.gnu',delimiter='      ',header=None,engine='python')
data_M=np.array(data)

X=data_M[:,0]
Y=data_M[:,1]
Z=data_M[:,2]
Xs=X.reshape((1000,1000))
Ys=Y.reshape((1000,1000))
Zs=Z.reshape((1000,1000))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
left, bottom, width, height = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
ax = fig.add_axes([left, bottom, width, height])

cp = plt.contourf(Xs, Ys, Zs)
plt.colorbar(cp)

ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 150)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 150)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.xlim(0, 25)
plt.ylim(0, 4)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Use python interactive plot so that you can use cursor to get value at that point in space

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just wanted to come back and check how things are going. Did you figure this out? Are you still working on it? Let us know! @Pranavkumar do you think you can extend that comment into an answer? It would be nice to get this question out of the unanswered queue!

Comment: Thanks @NikeDattani for the follow up. Still not figured out. It would be great if Pranav kumar or anyone else could suggest in an extended comment to an answer.

Comment: @Sak I have made an answer.  Please check if it answers your question. If it does please click on the tick mark next to it. You also get +2 if you do it. Also acknowledges the effort that goes into answering a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with a 3d interactive contour plot.
Here I have higlighted the current cursor position with a red dot.
It gives you all the x, y, z values at that point.
The below plot is generated with a small sample of your data from the screenshot of the x,y,z values.
I am plotting on a google colab notebook.

[image: 3d_contour_plot]

Install and initialize backend

```
!pip install ipympl

%matplotlib widget

from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()
```

Main code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d

data= [ [0,0,0.254], [0, 0.14,0.27], [0,0.29, 0.30], [0.1, 0.43, 0.31]] # Using a subset of your data
data_M = np.array(data)

X=data_M[:,0]
Y=data_M[:,1]
Z=data_M[:,2]

# change to 1000 for your original script
Xs=X.reshape((2,2))
Ys=Y.reshape((2,2))
Zs=Z.reshape((2,2))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(Xs, Ys, Zs)

ax.set_title('Contour Plot')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: +1 again! Since you said that you love Python I was going to send you a bunch of unanswered python questions that I thought you might be able to answer, with this one being on the top of the list! A bigger challenge though would be [my most recent question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10349/5) :)

Comment: if this question was worth answering, [might it be worth upvoting too](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/5)? Since the score is 1 and I upvoted, I know that others didn't :)